# Azure SQL Server Database creation not working correctly

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure

I have Azure and I just upgraded to the Pay-as-you-go option as I though being on the trial might be causing my issue, but it persists.

I try to make a database in SSMS and I get this error saying I don't have the right subscription:

[image]

The reason I want to do it from SSMS is because when I try to add the database through the azure portal it doesn't show up in the sys.database table:

[image]

One of my databases is dependent on another and can't find it when trying to add a stored procedure because it doesn't seem to be registering correctly with master.

What is going on and how do I fix it?

Comment: What is the version of ssms?

Comment: @Milen 13.0.16105.4

Comment: Have you tried creating database from portal / or powershell /?

Comment: How long ago did you upgrade?  I've found that the individual Azure services don't seem to notice the change in subscription status for a while (hours in some cases).

Comment: @Milen Yes, I created the database from the portal and it shows up in SSMS but it doesnt get registered. When check sys.databases it doesn't have a row for it.

Comment: @DeanGoodman about 12 hours ago.

Comment: Can you connect / open db with Visual Studio? Afaik ssms v13 is still in CTP. Can you try with 2014?

Comment: @milen I'll download 2014 and see.

Comment: @milen I downloaded the most recent production build and its the same as what I have. 16 installs13 for some reason. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. When making a new database you need to go to options and change service level to basic.